# Singleton class in IOKit based kext driver

Tags: c++, macos, kernel, iokit, xnu

I've got a class that maintain instance from type `class IOSharedDataQueue : public IODataQueue` which is IOKit object.

The class is decoupled and called from various methods of the main class, which is IOKit based class (derived from `IOService`).

While trying to convert this class to singleton, I've added the `getInstance` function with the following implementation :

```
myclass& myclass::getInstance()
{
    static myclass instance;
    return instance;
}
```

However, it seems that c++11 way of initialize singleton should work in IOKit compiler, and Xcode produces the following error :

`This initialization requires a guard variable, which the kernel does not support`

The thing is, that it works for classes that does't contain IOKIt based objects.

Perhaps anyone encounter this issue, I haven't seen any documentation of this limitation.

EDIT :

I've found out that if my class Does Not contain any IOResources object in any way, it can designed as a singleton with the guard variable.

However, I still want to be able to create some simple and contained wrappers to be used throughout my IOKit project without passing pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOKit objects are reference counted, and must always be instantiated with `new` and destroyed by calling `release()`. So regardless of the fact that thread-safe static initialisers aren't available in kexts, you shouldn't be statically allocating IOKit objects anyway. You can use an atomic pointer or a lock-based mechanism for instantiating your object on first call to the function, or create the instance at a fixed time.

An IOService as an explicit singleton is dubious anyway - are you sure you shouldn't be using IOResource based IOKit matching to create the single instance?

I'm suggesting something along the lines of:

```
static myclass* singleton_instance;
myclass* myclass::getInstance()
{
    if (singleton_instance == nullptr)
    {
        myclass* new_instance = new myclass();
        new_instance->init();
        if (!OSCompareAndSwapPtr(nullptr, new_instance, &singleton_instance))
        {
            new_instance->release();
        }
    }
    return singleton_instance;
}
// TODO: release singleton_instance when kext unloads
```

Comment: Indeed IOKit objects are referenced and I don't mind derived from `OSobject`, but I wish to use it throughout the project without passing pointers ... perhaps you can explain your suggestion about using `atomic pointers` ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, and you want to have a singleton instance of an `OSObject`-derived class, I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. I just wonder why IOKit doesn't allow static members inside objects ...

Comment: @Zohar81 I think it's because the compiler has to put a lock around the constructor. Did you try a non-iokit/osobject class with a nontrivial constructor?